# Which technique is more preferable iterative or recursive when memory resources are limited?

Tags: algorithm, performance, recursion, iteration

Does this approach depend upon compiler or language or what is the thing?
What is the ans for the question?

Comment: Iterative implementations in general have usually lower memory demands and are faster (in comparison to the same algo and complexity implemented recursively) because of less heap/stack trashing but this is depending also on the compiler/language. For example compilers designed for functional programming are better with recursion. So yes it depends on language/compiler. Common languages like C/C++ JAVA ... are better with iteration and functional ones (PROLOG,LISP but not sure if both was ages ago I used them last)

Comment: However there are algorithms and functions that are not worth doing iteratively as it would be too much work with almost no gain. Also if the recursion is not too deep then its fine to use recursive code as its usually much less and more comprehensable code. For example compare recursive and iterative implementation of [ackermann function](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/7206/6868)